# Azure Synapse vs Delta Lake

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, azure-synapse

I would like to know if there are any decision making factors between Azure Synapse vs Delta Lake(Databricks)?
in regards of performance/features/PRICE....

Given that the original design is that heavily rely on Store procedure (Azure Synapse) to do the transformation / build some tables(by simple aggregation function like sum/avg/count) for reporting dashboards.

Comment: anyone has the comment ?

Comment: Feature-wise, take into account that synapse is currently on delta 0.6.1 and consequently doesn't support some of the latest features.